# Object.values does not work typescript how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a cat that works js but does not work in typescript I get error:

```
Argument of type '{y: string; u: string; } [] 'is not assignable to parameter of type' ConcatArray <never>
```

I read that the problem may be in `Object.values()`,The article says that I also changed the configuration `tsconfig.json` I did, but the error did not disappear. [Object.values error Vido](https://youtu.be/2zZijOYDc6c)

code

```
 const x = {
    man: [
      {
        y: "y",
        u: "u"
      }
    ],
    woman: [
      {
        y: "y",
        u: "u"
      }
    ]
  };

  function Y() {
    return ([].concat(...Object.values(x)));
  }

  console.log(Y());
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is that the array `[]` has the type of `never[]`. If you cast `[]` to `unknown[]` it will work.

```
const x = {
  man: [
    {
      y: "y",
      u: "u"
    }
  ],
  woman: [
    {
      y: "y",
      u: "u"
    }
  ]
};

function Y() {
  return (([] as unknown[]).concat(...Object.values(x)));
}

console.log(Y());
```

**Edit:**

I would actually recommend you to use `return Object.values(x).flat();` instead of concat. It will do the exact same thing and you don't need to cast the array.

Comment: mozilla.org say that Array.prototype.flat () This is an experimental technology.In the future, there will be no problems?

Comment: I don't see that it says it's experimental on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat. However, I can see that it's quite recent. It really depends on what you need to run it on. If you only need it to run on the latest version of Chrome and Firefox I don't see a problem. If you need it to actually work on older browsers then you will either have to use concat again or use babel to transpile it to es5.

Comment: Thanks for your reply